# What is the iPhone ringer alert popup name?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

what is the iPhone ringer alert popup name? and could implement that ?  i mean like this :

[alt text http://freezpic.com/pics/e53bcff753bd37294dcfa7ecf494af1d.PNG](http://freezpic.com/pics/e53bcff753bd37294dcfa7ecf494af1d.PNG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a built-in control, but there is an open source project (http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) which creates a rounded translucent view. Although used for showing progress, it can be adapted.

It will take some tinkering with, but hopefully it's a push in the right direction.